# iOS where to temporary save information

Tags: ios, memory-management

I have a question about performance and memory usage. I want to temporarily save about 200 NSStrings and output them later on. You can see a little storyboard of the app in the attachment.

Currently i made 200 NSStrings in my AppDelegate and i am accessing them through this code:

```
AppDelegate *appData = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appData.customString = @"customText";
```

The output view should generate a pdf with the 200 Strings and then the Strings can be released.

Any advice for a better way to store the information?

Comment: Do you actually have a problem with your current method? How long should they be saved?

Comment: are those strings all the time the same or they are changing? if yes on what basis they are modified?

Comment: Please provide move info on performance and memory concerns and string nature. 200 small strings like 'customText' in an `NSArray` are neither affecting performance nor memory.

Comment: this was kind of my question. 200 string each not longer than 200 word won´t much affect the memory? And i think when i add 5 images (size 1000px*1000px) i would be the same case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Singleton class named "ApplicationManager" and store your data in it. As this class is singleton, you can use it everywhere in the application and keep the AppDelegate clean.

Comment: It shouldn't be a singleton, and it shouldn't have such a generic and thus meaningless name as `ApplicationManager`.

Comment: why should´t is be a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy evaluation.
Use a @property and create no ivars. 
Then create a setter and getter where the `NSArray *` with the string as elements will be generated/deallocated.

In the getter you could release everything.
The handling is easy through the dot-syntax, everything is encapsulated in the *calculated property*